# How to provide environments variables to docker compose command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, rasa

I have three files `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`, and `entrypoint.sh`.

Dockerfile

```
FROM rasa/rasa:3.1.0-full

ADD . /app

RUN whoami

USER root

RUN pip install google-cloud-storage

USER rasa

CMD [ "rasa", "run", "--enable-API", "--auth-token", "secret", "--model", "abc.gz" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  rasa:
    image: himanshu/rasa:dev
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command: ["run", "--enable-API", "--auth-token", "secret","--model", "abc.gz"]
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/dev.json
      - BUCKET_NAME=customer-service-rasa-models
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# VARIABLES
BUCKET_NAME=gs://customer-service-rasa-models-staging
PROJECT_NAME=intelagent-dev
KEY_FILE=./dev.json

#LOGIN TO GCLOUD
gcloud auth activate-service-account --project=$PROJECT_NAME --key-file=$KEY_FILE

# Run gsutil command 
FILE_NAME=`gsutil ls -l $BUCKET_NAME | sort -k2 | tail -n2 | head -n1 | awk 'END {$1=$2=""; sub(/^[ \t]+/, ""); print }'` 
echo $FILE_NAME
# Then run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

**Problem:** I am new to docker. I have `--model` in CMD, which have a default value of `abc.gz` currently, but I want to set this dynamically every time docker restart, which I can get from the `entrypoint.sh` FILE_NAME field, but I am not sure how to set --model value from `entrypoint.sh` FILE_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `CMD` to:

```
["/bin/bash", "-c", "run --enable-API --auth-token secret --model $FILE_NAME"]
```

In your `docker-compose.yaml` file remove the `command` attribute as it's the same defined in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thanks, where will I run the entrypoint.sh?

Comment: Oh just add another instruction in your `Dockerfile` before `CMD`, for example if you're copying entrypoint.sh to the /app folder, just add `ENTRYPOINT  ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]`